# Cocoapads Install Overwrites changed code on Pods Projects?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I wonder if I "pod install", Does it overwrite the code I have changed on Pods project?

I know "pod update" overwrites, but I am not sure "pod install" does.

Comment: Yes! If you `pod install` all changes will be overwritten.

Comment: Ofcourse it does.